How do I access MongoDB database as part of a larger Vue application
I am self-taught and new to the nuts & bolts of the 'build' process and web application structure in general, so hopefully I can even phrase this question correctly. Dependencies, pulling in packages, and config files are hard for me to stitch together in my mind logically, but I believe I've got it down to this:
-I have successfully connected to my free MongoDB database with a connection string via Node.JS
import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from 'mongodb'
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<otherURLStuff>";

const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  }
});

export const data = await client.db('PlayerData').collection('PlayerData').find()

-I have a simple Vue component that's just trying to display the data returned:
<script setup>
const { data } = await useFetch('noIdeaIfThisIsRight')

console.log(data)

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ data }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>


When I do this, I've been getting a 'util_1.promisify doesn't exist' error, and other times I get 500 errors, and other times I don't know what is wrong because I am missing some critical knowledge gaps, I think.

So my question really is, what is happening here? And how do I connect the data (which I've verified is successfully retrieved from my MongoDB Atlas cluster) to my Vue 3 application?
I suspect I'm missing some basic server-client interaction understanding, but I have unfortunately lost my objectivity for doing effective Google-ing. Thanks in advance for any help!
I've tried Nuxt.JS useFetch(), but may be using it wrong. I've also tried the Fetch API, but I think I'm using it wrong. Generally speaking, I think I may be missing some understanding of how clients and server interact.

So you have a NodeJS app somewhere and a Nuxt app on the other side? Can you try Postman or similar to double-check if you can reach your MongoDB successfully? What do you see in your devtools' network tab? Try to use a more basic $fetch in Nuxt, because useFetch() is a bit more advanced. Nuxt environment can be a bit tricky to fully understand (server/client, isomorphic places, hydration etc) so you could have a hard time knowing where and how to use things. But you could maybe give a try to that specific module? https://nuxt-mongoose.nuxt.space/ It's an abstraction but might be easier.

Your Vue  is a client application and it runs in a web browser. To get data into your Vue program you can access the database data via APIs. The APIs are built with a server side program of the web application - this is a NodeJS application and uses a library like ExpressJS to create the APIs. Then, use the Fetch calls to  access the APIs in your Vue program.

Thanks @kissu, I will give that a shot. Currently, I've been running my server/index.js f and successfully pinging my MongoDB database. The db() returns the 5 documents in the collection, and prints it by console.log() which is great! --- But when I try to export the variable to a Vue SFC it always states that util_1.promisify is not a function. I'm glad you mentioned the $fetch, useFetch() is definitely more complicated. I appreciate your insights and will try mongoose!

Thanks @prasad_ that was a great high-level explanation. In my case, I don't think I have anything like ExpressJS at all to 'expose' my data to my application. Is that the right way of thinking about this?
So then say ExpressJS might 'expose' the data to localhost:3000 and I can call my $fetch to grab the data from there?
I feel like I'm so close, and appreciate your explanation!

Also as a bit of advice - keep your server side and VUE app as different projects) otherwise things can get really messy)

@NikitaMazur disagree. Nuxt can be a decent small backend solution thanks to Nitro.

@dchisholm125 See ExpressJS - Basic Routing.
